# Using Show to place a ParametricPlot on a LogLog scale

Tags: plotting, graphics, logarithmic-scale

I wish to have a few plots on the same graph: ListLogLogPlot, LogLogPlot and a ParametricPlot drawing lines perpendicular to the x-axis. The problem is however that ParametricPlot doesn't seem to have the LogLog equivalent, as the other Plot functions do, and Show does not combine non-LogLog plots with LogLog plots, even when they coincide, eg.:

```
Show[LogLogPlot[x^4, {x,10^(-10),10^10}], Plot[x^5, {x,10^(-10),10^10}]]
```

should theoretically show two straight lines, but shows only one. Is there a way to combine such graphics without resolving to using non-LogLog plots?

Comment: @Öskå Well, it was just an example... Anyway thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Show[{
  LogLogPlot[x^4, {x, 10^(-10), 10^10}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
  LogLogPlot[x^5, {x, 10^(-10), 10^10}, PlotStyle -> Blue],
  ParametricPlot[{Log[0.01], Log[y]}, {y, 10^-26, 10^30}, 
   PlotStyle -> Darker@Green]
  }]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, it works! I thought I tested out this possibility as well... Anyway it makes sense $-$ thanks!