# Logarithm scaling of y-axis in paramteric plot

Tags: graphics

Logarithm Scaling of a normal plot is fairly simply with the LogPlot command but I couldn't find anything for scaling a for scaling of a parametric plot.

If I want to draw a paramteric plot with y-scaled logarithmically how would I do that?

Comment: use the option `ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log"}`?

Comment: I think "ParametricPlot" can not do this directly. But you can plot the Log of the y coordinate.

Comment: `f[t_] = 2 t;
g[t_] = Exp[t^2];
ParametricPlot[MapAt[Log, 2]@{f[t], g[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]`

Comment: Can the method suggested by @JasonB in his answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115977/logarithmic-scale-in-an-parametricplot-obtained-from-ode-boundary-conditions) be adapted?

Comment: Notwithstanding the warning and highlighting that "`ScalingFunctions` is not an option for `ParametricPlot`" , kglr\`s recommendation to use `ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log"}` gives the desired result. Alternatively, extract the points from `ParametricPlot` and use `ScalingFunctions -> "Log"` with `ListLinePlot`, e.g., `ListLinePlot[Cases[ParametricPlot[{2 t, E^(t^2)}, {t, -1.5, 1.5}], Line[ pts_ ] :> pts, Infinity], ScalingFunctions -> "Log", AspectRatio -> 1]`